# Easy way to sync Firebird and MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, firebird

I know that some of you might assume that this topic is to broad / general but currently im hopeless. I'm looking for a solution to sync two databases:
1. Offline firebird database
2. Online mysql database

DB #1 is not offline in 100% (of course there is internet connection to the PC) but I want to avoid using direct access to the computer.

**What I would like to achieve?**

Get data from database #1 (two tables: sales & customers) and pump it to database #2 which is on my hosting. On hosting im displaying this data via PHP.

**Current solution:**

1. Using fbexport tool im getting the data from firebird database and export it as a file ( as SQL inserts ).
2. Using FTP i've got scheduled jobs to few times per day upload this file to server
3. ON a server i'm using cron jobs & PHP script to pump data to mysql

**Problems with solution:**

I think that my solution is a bit amateur one.. on one hand i want to avoid any extra costs (e.g. buying license for dbconvert tool) but on the other i want to get access to this data more often than now (i'm exporting data 3 times per day).

I'm not looking for ready-code solutions, rather for guidelines like: take a look on this tool and then by my own i would go through documentation.. thanks

Comment: Looking for tool suggestions and external resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Instead I have closed as duplicate as a similar question a few days ago. Otherwise I suggest you post to the firebird-tools mailinglist or maybe the firebird-support mailinglist.